# Texto Colorido CSS javaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, button

Tenho um Button e estou usando javaFX, o que preciso: o texto do botão está escrito Buscar, preciso que o 'B' esteja na cor vermelha e o "uscar" na cor padrão, já tentei de tudo e não estou conseguindo fazer isto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar o botão com um texto adicional dentro:

```
<Button fx:id="button" graphicTextGap="0.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="uscar">
    <graphic>
        <Text fill="RED" strokeMiterLimit="0.0" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="B" />
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

Dessa forma o primeiro caractere vai estar na cor defina em `fill`, e o restante vai ter o estilo do botão.

No botão é necessário deixar o valor de `graphicTextGap` zerado para que a primeira letra não fique separada do resto do texto

[image: Botão com a primeira letra com cor diferente]

Comment: desculpe a minha ignorância, mas como  eu adiciono um texto adicional dentro?

Comment: O texto "uscar" ficaria no botão, dentro do botão você coloca: <graphic>
        <Text fill="RED" strokeMiterLimit="0.0" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="B" />
    </graphic>, essa parte vai deixar o "B" dentro do botão com a cor vermelha

Comment: Não achei uma forma de fazer somente com css, só consegui fazer dentro do fxml

Comment: entã0 eu adicionei esse comando, só que está dando erro no Scene Builder, diz que tem código que não foi possível ler

Comment: Faz assim: cria um botão no scene builder, depois arrasta um text para dentro do botão, no text você coloca o "B", no text "uscar", depois em properties do botão você coloca o valor de Graphic Text Gap como 0

Comment: mas isso ai não seria uma gambiarra? eu consegui fazer com CSS porem dependendo do tamanho da palavra eu preciso ficar reajustando, eu queria entender esse código para que dentro do netbeans eu pudesse fazer o raciocínio para padronizar, assim não tem como padronizar, pois a formatação ficará no view

Answer (score 0):

Você só irá alcançar este resultado fazendo isso manualmente, pode utilizar o método `textFill` para a alcançar o resultado. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
 public class ColoredButtonTextDemo extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

            HBox coloredTextBox = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(0).children(
                    LabelBuilder.create().text("B").textFill(Color.RED).build(),
                    LabelBuilder.create().text("uscar")textFill(Color.BLACK).build();

            btn.setGraphic(coloredTextBox);
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(btn);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```